# Can I use cross-validation to make predictions?

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models, scikit-learn

Hi I am a beginner and I am confused about whether I can make predictions with the models produced during kfold. For example in the code below, the model produced in each kfold was used to make predictions on the test set.

```
auc = []
test_pred = []
# GroupKFold
kf = GroupKFold(n_splits=5)
for fold, (idx_train, idx_valid) in enumerate(kf.split(train, train['failure'], train['product_code'])):
    xtrain = train.iloc[idx_train][test.columns]
    xvalid = train.iloc[idx_valid][test.columns]
    ytrain = train.iloc[idx_train]['failure']
    yvalid = train.iloc[idx_valid]['failure']
    xtest = test.copy()

    features = [f for f in xtrain.columns if f != 'product_code']
    model = make_pipeline(preprocessor, LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', random_state=1, solver = 'liblinear',C= 0.01,class_weight = 'balanced'))
    model.fit(xtrain[features], ytrain)

    preds_valid = model.predict_proba(xvalid[features])[:,1]
    score = roc_auc_score(yvalid, preds_valid)
    print(f"Fold {fold}: auc = {score:0.5f}")
    auc.append(score)

    test_pred.append(model.predict_proba(xtest[features])[:,1])

print(f"Average auc = {sum(auc) / 5:.5f}")

submission = pd.DataFrame({'id': test.index,
                           'failure': sum(test_pred)/5})
```

This [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411290/how-to-use-a-cross-validated-model-for-prediction) talks about the cross_validate function, if I take each estimator generated by the function and use it to make the predictions in the test, wouldn't that be the same thing done in that code?

I would like to know if this kind of approach is normal or if I am making a mistake.

Comment: In some sense, sure. In another sense, why bother? You have the true observations.

Comment: In the "train, cross-validate, test" paradigm, where the cross-validation folds are taken from the training set, for each fold you train possible models on the rest of the training data not in that fold and test it against the data in the fold.  You use this to select your model and hyper-parameters.  One you have done that you should then train that model with those hyper-parameters on the full training set and finally (and only once) test it against the test set you set aside at the beginning to see how good this final model is on unseen data.